# Cordova ipad app 100% height issue

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, ipad

I just made an ios app through cordova, iphone app looks fine because I am using always portrait mode for iphones but for ipads I am using always landscape mode with locked rotation. The problem is when I ma build an app and run it on my ipad the landscape works fine the rotation is locked but the main issue is that I have set 100% height on body, and somehow its not working on iPad landscape. Looks like that 100% doesnt detect landscape mode and automatically was set 1024px for height because if I am set 768px height for body in inspect then the whole app looks fine as should.

Any ideas what can be the issue there ?

Comment: are you using a viewport meta tag?

Comment: Yes I am using, on portrait mode is working fine just landcape mode makes that issue with detecting correct height when I am using 100% height in css

Comment: then provide it on the question...

Comment: @jcesarmobile `<meta name="viewport" id="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0, width=device-width, height=device-height">`

Comment: try removing the height=device-height

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't set width and height if you set the scale

From [apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/UsingtheViewport/UsingtheViewport.html)

> You do not need to set every viewport property. If only a subset of
>   the properties are set, then Safari on iOS infers the other values.
>   For example, if you set the scale to 1.0, Safari assumes the width is
>   device-width in portrait and device-height in landscape orientation.